# Add js library to visual studio project

Tags: javascript

I need to add to my C# web project a JS [library](https://github.com/wout/svg.js), but i still don`t get how to do it. There is no such library in the built-in Nuget Package manager. Thanks for any help ;)

Comment: JavaScript libraries are generally just files: download the file and put it in your project. Or use a client side package manager, ex Bower. Or reference it from the CDN it's hosted on.

Comment: "C# Web project" is quite a broad label that encompasses ASP.NET Web Forms, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Web API, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download the file and then just copy/paste the `*.js` file in your project and take a reference of it in your design page `*.aspx` (for ASP.NET) or `*.cshtml` (for ASP.NET MVC) saying

```
<script src="~/filename.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was the key line that I couldn't find.